# Positive dimension for modular forms with weight 2.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading William A. Stein's book "Modular Forms: A Computational Approach". In Chapter 3 of this book, he studies Modular Forms of Weight 2. One can also refer to the following website about this Chapter.

[Modular Forms of Weight 2.](https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/weight_two.html)

I used Sage to calculate dimension for $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ and I found that for $N>1$ the space $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ has positive dimensions. Then I tried to prove this by using the dimensional formula in Diamond and Shurman's book concerning to elliptic point of order 2, 3 and $\infty$. I failed.

Is this claim right? Does the space $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ have positive dimensions
for all $N>1$?

---

I also believe that it is right because @Somos pointed that the OEIS sequence A111248 gives the dimension of $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ for $N<1000$. Now I am wondering how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated!:)

Answer (score 1):

The Eisenstein Series

$$E_2(\tau) = 1 - 24 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n q^n}{1 - q^n}$$

is not quite an element of $M_2(\Gamma_0(1)) = 0$; although it satisfies $E_2(\tau+1) = E_2(\tau)$,
it "only" satisfies

$$E_2\left(\frac{-1}{\tau}\right) = \tau^2 E_2(\tau) - \frac{6 i \tau}{\pi}.$$

On the other hand, if $N$ is any integer, then, if one lets

$$E^*_2(\tau) = E_2(\tau) - N E_2(N \tau),$$

an elementary argument shows that $E^*_2(\tau) \in M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$, and it is clearly non-zero for $N > 1$. So the dimension is always at least one.

---

For a second argument, the space of weight two modular forms is given by $H^0(X_0(N),\Omega^1_X(\infty))$,
the holomorphic differentials on the compactified modular curve with at worst simple poles at the cusps $\infty$. (Equivalently, holomorphic forms on the upper half plane whose Fourier expansion only has non-negative powers of $q$ --- at infinity $2 \pi i d \tau = dq/q$ so non-cusp forms have simple poles at cusps). One way to construct such a form is as follows.
Let $\Delta(\tau) \in S_{12}(\Gamma_0(1))$ be the Ramanujan Delta function which is non-vanishing away from the cusp, where it has a simple zero. Thus $\Delta(N \tau)/\Delta(\tau)$ is a meromorphic function on $X_0(N)$ which is holomorphic away from the cusps where it
 has at worst a simple pole. But then

$$ \frac{d}{d \tau} \log \left(\frac{\Delta(N \tau)}{\Delta(\tau)}r\right)$$

is a holomorphic differential with at worst simple poles at the cusps, so gives an element of $H^0(X_0(N),\Omega^1_X(\infty))$, which is non-zero for $N > 1$.

**Exercise:** These two constructions give the same modular form up to  a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [OEIS sequence A111248](https://oeis.org/A111248) gives the dimension of
 $\, M_2(\Gamma_0(N)) \,$ and has a link to a document "Modular Forms on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$" by Steven Finch which has over 100 bibliography items. Also see Jeremy Rouse and John J. Webb, [*On Spaces of Modular Forms Spanned by Eta-Quotients*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1460).

Comment: Thanks. It's true but how to prove it.

Comment: Thank you for your reference! I find the result there! But it seems that they omit the proof of the result.